# How do I pass values from a collection to as custom HTML attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am writing a form in Rails. I have a collection of users which includes the following user details

- name
- last_name
- id
- employee_id

I would like to define the user names to appear as the dropdown **display** values while their ids are the dropdown **values** but at the same time I would like to add an additional custom HTML attribute which is data-employee-id and is set to be the same as the employeeId

My current code is as follows:

```
.user-dropdown
  = f.label 'name'
  = f.input :id, as: :select, collection: @users, include_blank: }
```

The html result would be as follows:

```
<option value='1' data-employee-id='1234'>Alex</option>
<option value='2' data-employee-id='2468'>Bradley</option>
<option value='3' data-employee-id='1357'>Cathy</option>
```

Comment: What form builder gem are you using? Formtastic or Simple Form. I will remove the haml tag, since it's not relevant to the question.

Comment: It's the simple form, thanks for updating the question :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using [options_for_select](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_for_select)

```
= f.select :id, options_for_select(
  @users.map { |u| [u.name, u.id, {'data-employee-id' => u.id}] })
```

Answer (score 0):

simple form has it's perks so Mihai's answer is close
The simple_form way would be

```
= f.input :id, collection: @users.map { |u| [u.name, u.id] }, 
include_blank: true/false
```

and also you left a closing curly brace without opening it.

Comment: You are missing the point of the question: How to set: `data-employee-id` in the option tags.